# How to keep a facebook likebox on the same line as a header tag?

Tags: html, css, facebook

Hey, I want to add a likebox beside my header tag (h2) and keep it on the same line. So it appears like: `This is the Title LikeBox`

However what is happening is the likebox is going starting on a new line like this:

```
This is the Title
LikeBox
```

Is there anyone willing to help me with this? If it's possible?

My css is :

```
.post-details h2 {
border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and html code is:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?><h2>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="50" rel="nofollow"></fb:like>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonny `h1,h2,h3,<p>` they all takes 100% width automatically . So, you have to given float to your `h2` tag

```
.post-details h2 {
float:left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
font-weight: bold;
}
#fb-root {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<div id="fb-root">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="50" rel="nofollow"></fb:like>
</div>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Then in your CSS, add:

```
#fb-root {
    float: right;
}
```